# Zend framework 2 recommended way for error handling

Tags: php, zend-framework, error-handling, zend-framework2

I noticed  that the Skeleton Application that Zend provides does not handle `error 500`. I know that in ZF1 there was an `ErrorController` that took care of that. I have done some research online, but did not find a clear cut solution for this.

So what is the best way for error handling in ZF2. Would it be on per module basis or some global exception/error handler?

I know that another solution would be to add `ini_set('display_errors', true);` to my `index.php`, but I don't really like that solution. It seems that the framework should provide some way for handling errors.

Comment: Errors are handled quite well in the skeleton application. What is it you are trying to do? The question is unclear. ([error 500 template declaration](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L84), [errors on/off switch](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L81))

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can handle the exceptions in anyway you want after catching it as the following example in which you are catching the exception globally...:

In the `onBootstrap` method in your `Module.php` you can attach a function to execute when an event occurs, the following attach a function to be executed when an error (exception) is raised:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $application = $e->getApplication();
    $em = $application->getEventManager();
    //handle the dispatch error (exception) 
    $em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, array($this, 'handleError'));
    //handle the view render error (exception) 
    $em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER_ERROR, array($this, 'handleError'));
}
```

and then define the function to handle the error in any way you want, the following is an example:

```
public function handleError(MvcEvent $e)
{
    //get the exception
    $exception = $e->getParam('exception');
    //...handle the exception... maybe log it and redirect to another page, 
    //or send an email that an exception occurred...
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how we redirect to another page from within handleError function?

Comment: we're running APIs application, working like a charm, thanks man :)

Comment: @Mohammad Control doesnt come to handlerError() if in header we send: application/json. Any idea how to fix this? -H 'Accept: application/json'