# How can I use error handler from skeleton project 'Application' module to catch errors in event callbacks?

Tags: php, error-handling, zend-framework2

I am trying to attach a callback to 'dispatch' event in ZF2 event manager to automatically authenticate on every request.

```
// Auth/Module.php
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

        $eventManager->attach(
            MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,
            array($this, 'authCallback')
        );

        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    }

    public function authCallback(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        // SNIP

        if (! $authenticated) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException('Yada yada');
        }
    }
```

I throw an exception if authentication fails and I want to handle this using the error handling built into the [skeleton-project Application module](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/tree/master/module/Application). The problem I'm having is it seems to be handling errors thrown in controllers but wont handle the exception thrown by the auth service in the callback ('dispatch' event hook)

I tried attaching the callback to a different event like 'finish' or 'render' and I tried changing the priority when attaching the event but nothing has worked. How do I catch this exception using the existing error handler?

I also tried setting an error on the event in the callback like this

```
    public function authCallback(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $auth = \Zend_Auth::getInstance();

        // SNIP
        if (! $authenticated) {
            $event->setError('somethings wrong');
        }
    }
```

but when I do this there is no error handled and the original request goes through regardless.

Comment: Where is "the error handling" you are referring to? can you post the code? anyway this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890536/zend-framework-2-recommended-way-for-error-handling/16909752

Comment: You can trigger the `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR` error from within your event listener or alternatively you can modify or return the `Response` (as it is within the dispatch loop) such as `$event->getResponse()->setStatusCode(403)`

Comment: @MohammadZeinEddin In the Application module that comes with zend skeleton application. https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php it uses 'view_manager' config to render error view when an exception is thrown. But not when it's thrown in dispatch hook apparently. Also I tried attaching a callback to EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR but this event never gets fired if the exception is thrown within the other 'authCallback' callback

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to set the error and exception on the event and then trigger EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR instead of just throwing the exception.

```
public function authCallback(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $auth = \Zend_Auth::getInstance();

    // SNIP
    if (! $authenticated) {
        $event->setError('Something happened')
            ->setParam(
                'exception',
                new UnauthorizedException('blah blah')
            );

        $event->getApplication()
            ->getEventManager()
            ->trigger(
                MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR,
                $this,
                $event
            );
    }
}
```