# zend framework 2 do not catch all errors

Tags: error-handling, zend-framework2

Hello everyone I followed the instructions provided here

[Zend framework 2 recommended way for error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890536/zend-framework-2-recommended-way-for-error-handling)

to catch any errors that occur including notice

works fine for fatal errors and exceptions but for the notice. there is a way to capture them?

unfortunately I can not add comments to the discussion I mentioned and also two years old

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a custom error handler for that. Have a look at this blog post: https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/zend-framework-2-handle-e-php-error/

I'm not sure if this is the best example of an error handler, you might not want to send an e-mail every time something happens. But at least it will show you how to get one up and running in ZF2.

Comment: I set as a response but have not been able to verify all the details. Apparently you should also set the display of the notice to be able to intercept and I believe that in production is not a wise move

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

or more preferably setting

```
error_reporting E_ALL & E_NOTICE & E_STRICT
```

in your php.ini file